# How to store huge String data in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, out-of-memory

When we initialize a String array

```
String [] data = {"..." , "...", .....};
```

Let, the above array contains 1000 String data, do all the data get loaded in RAM simultaneously?

If it is so, then if the data is huge, the app may crash being out of memory.
So how can I avoid this?

Also, is storing data in Data Base like SQLite a solution of the problem?

Comment: 1. Yes, eventually you might run out of memory. 2. By not keeping it in memory 3. yes, storing it anywhere outside of ram reduces its ram footprint, obviously. Where you store it depends on what you want to do with the data. How much data are you actually talking about? How big is each string?

Comment: One option: Paginate your data, and only load it in chunks, as your application logic needs it.

Comment: I am new in Android and I am unaware of such cool stuff... Will grow slowly! Just clear one thing are the SQLite data stored in RAM or Hard Drive during the Run time

Comment: `Let, the above array contains 1000 String data, ` Even if every string is 1000 chars it would only be one or two MB. That is not much. Would you type that like that in your source code? Better put it in a text file which you put in assets.

Comment: `Also, is storing data in Data Base like SQLite a solution of the problem?` You cannot store data in sqlite at design time. And you can also not store data in shared preferences at design time.

Comment: Oh that's superb if it requires only 2MB !! Putting the entire Strings in a text file is a better option according to you ... Can you please help me out with the reason of your such suggetion?

Comment: I already told you: you will not type that in your source code but in a file which you manage separately.

Comment: Ohkay thanku for your help 

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use a database for this problem, because basically if you just want to store string you have something pretty cool in Android that you can use which is called "SharedPreferences". This will allow you to store your strings in a dictionnary that only your application will be able to reach on the phone.

Comment: people abuse shared-prefs for a lot of things, if OP is saving a lot of large strings then the shared prefs file might grow really quickly and it will remain on the users phone afterwards. also, shared-prefs _can_ be accessed by other apps, you have to specifically implement it to not allow this

Comment: "Use shared storage for user data that can or should be accessible to other apps and saved even if the user uninstalls your app." [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared)

Comment: Shared prefs cannot be accessed by other apps. Please show how it can be accessed. But using shared prefs is impossible as that string was declared at design time.

Comment: Why not ? Basically, it seems like he wants to use strings during his whole app, and it might be the best idea to keep them in a file, like with SharedPreferences. But yeah, if he wants to load more strings every time the app is getting used, that might not be a good idea to store them in a file, and he should rather use a database in this case

Comment: I am new with android Studio and I don't know how to use SharedPreferences  I am aware with SQLite Database. I want to ask that whether the SQLite data is stored in hard drive or in RAM during the Run Time?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html 
"SQLite uses dynamic memory allocation to obtain memory for storing various objects (ex: database connections and prepared statements) and to build a memory cache of the database file and to hold the results of queries. Much effort has gone into making the dynamic memory allocation subsystem of SQLite reliable, predictable, robust, secure, and efficient."
Basically, it seems that your data will be on hard drive but any result of query will be kept on RAM, you should take a look at SQLite documentation a bit

Comment: Okhay thanx for your help